# access violation in pointer allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, unique-ptr, allocation, access-violation

I want to put random data into `arr` (pointer allocation). How can I put data into that dynamic allocation?

```
typedef unique_ptr<unique_ptr<int[]>[]> uniquePtr;

uniquePtr arr = make_unique<unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(size);
    
srand(time(NULL));
cout << "size: " << endl;

cin >> size;
int max = size * size;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % max; //error!
    }
}
```

Type of `arr[i][j]` is `int`.
When I tried this code,

```
arr[i][j] = new int(rand() % max);
```

but, the error is

```
arr[i][j] is int type and new int(~) is int* type
```

I want to put random int data into arr allocation.

Comment: Remove the `new`.  `int(...)` has the type _`int`_, and `new int(...)` has the type _`int*`_.

Comment: Looks like this isn't the actual code you're running/compiling.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are only using make_unique on 1 of the 2 dimensions.

Comment: You have pointers to pointers. That means you have to initialize with `arr[i] = make_unique<int[]>(size)` in a loop. You can then set with `arr[i][j] = rand() % max`. (BTW there are more modern random number functions now)

Comment: Also consider using `std::array` instead. If you use C++23 with gcc or clang you can use multidimensional array access with `[i, j]`, but there are no types (`std::mdspan` and `std::mdarray`) agreed upon yet supporting the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you did not dynamically allocate the second dimension.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int size = 5;
    
    typedef unique_ptr<unique_ptr<int[]>[]> uniquePtr;

    uniquePtr arr = make_unique<unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(size);
        
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "size: " << endl;
    
    cin >> size;
    int max = size * size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Dynamically allocate the row 
        arr[i] = make_unique<int[]>(size);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % max; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I put this online here: https://ideone.com/llAvTD

Comment: Thank you for answering! But the code succeed only in int main(). I copy and paste this in my class, but it also had access violation.... If you know difference, could you give me the additional answer?

My code in class:
`void JYJGame::makeBingo()
{
 uniquePtr arr = make_unique<unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(size);

 srand(time(NULL));
 cout << "size: " << endl;

 cin >> size;
 int max = size * size;
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  arr[i] = make_unique<int[]>(size);
  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
   arr[i][j] = rand() % max;
   cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Perhaps you have some other `arr` variable. In `makeBingo()` arr is a local variable to this function. It no longer exists after the function ends.

Comment: Also if you have a debugger like the one in Visual Studio it will tell you where the access violation is.